"It is recommended for us to have eaten…” Is this grammatical?
I'd like to ask you because I wrote one sentence on my exam and it was marked as incorrect and there was no reason stated why it was wrong. To me, I'm sure I made no mistake. Could you check it so at least I know what the mistake is if there is?
"It is recommended for us to have eaten something before swimming."
Is there really a mistake?

https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/the-subjunctive and https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/subjunctive.php

@Mari-LouA How does it help? I dont aks about "it is recommended that" and subjunctive but about "it is recommended to and infinitves

One finds in Alien Abduction for Professionals: Steamy Reverse Harem by Skye MacKinnon ( Peryton Press, 2021):

We'd done some weightlifting before we abducted Trish —the course had recommended for us to look our best so to attract our female —but that was a while ago now. I swore I would do regular cardio as soon as we were safely back on the Jade.

and in Mastering Academic Writing by Boba Samuels and Jordana Garbati (SAGE Publications, 2018)

Firstly, they recommended for us to use a gate instead of leaving an opening in the fence. Secondly, they recommended for us to use better quality posts as the ones we had were unlikely to go past two winters.

But this is very clunky writing.  There is no need to use a construction as cumbersome as they recommended for us to ... and very few competent writers would do so nowadays.
One could use the verb advise instead:

They advised us to use a gate instead of leaving an opening in the fence.
We were advised to install a gate.

Though "install" would be better than "use" if your goal is to sound not too talky.
And if you're going to use recommend the mainstream use is

They recommmended that we...

But the construction is not unpopular.

Are you the downvoter? If you were, can you help me understand why my answer is incorrect or misleading? Thanks.

So apart from the "for us" which you find clumsy, the rest of the OP's sentence is acceptable. "Mainstream use" is the one I showed in my answer, the "subjunctive mood" but I imagine the OP or any nonnative speaker to interpret the silent ellipsis dots saying rest is fine: It is recommended that we have eaten something before swimming.

@Mari-LouA It is not just "for us" in the OP's example, but the dummy It in combination with recommended and an infinitival clause with to have eaten; "It is recommended for us to have eaten"   Those features combine to produce an awkwardness.  If I were a track coach and the athlete ran like that, I'd suggest another sport or a change in how they ran.

Are you aware of how many hits there are in the google search string: "They recommended  for us to…" I counted 39. In my books that is precisely unpopular And I would not recommend this construction to any learner.

But did you see how many times it appears on the web, where it is more likely that an editor hasn't tidied things up?

Breaking News: people don't always write in grammatical English. You haven't denied it, so can I ask  why you downvoted my answer?

@Mari-LouA  I didn't downvote it and just upvoted it.

OK. Thanks I wasn't expecting that.

@Mari-LouA It is recommended for you not to assume your answers are in my crosshairs :-)

@TimR I think there  is a difference between for instance "she recommmends" after which I would only use subjunctive and "it is recommended" where using "to" seems to be okay. That's why I think my original sentence is correct. Would you agree?

@Adam  Recommend is usually followed by a that-clause in which the verb will be shifted to the bare form by many speakers:  She recommends that he take the train not the bus..  recommends can also be followed by an infinitival clause, though it is somewhat dated usage nowadays: She recommends to visit the Louvre.  or It is recommended to visit the Louvre.  The latter is an impersonal construction, which makes for us odd.

@TimR would it sound better to you if I used "It is important for us to have eaten something before swimming." Instead of recommended?

@Adam *It is important for us to have {done something} before {doing something}" is grammatical and idiomatic, though a tad towards the formal end of the spectrum.  We should do something before {doing something} would be the neutral way of expressing the idea, neither formal nor informal.   We should buy the return tickets before leaving. It is important for you to have completed Phase I training before attempting Phase 2.


It is recommended for us to have eaten something before swimming.

The sentence above was marked wrong without an explanation. It is likely that their teacher was expecting a sentence similar to this:

It is recommended that we eat something before swimming.

There are probably two reasons why the OP's sentence was marked incorrect.

Formal grammar dictates that we use the base form (without to).
The negative form would make greater sense:


It is recommended that we SHOULD NOT eat anything before swimming.

It was once  believed that anyone who ate a meal, especially a heavy one, had to wait between 30 and one hour before going swimming. This was and remains a myth; the danger of drowning do not increase if a person eats before bathing. However, I don't believe anyone would actually advise eating before jumping in the cool waters of the ocean or a swimming pool.
See Mayo Clinic Minute: Should you wait 30 minutes to swim after eating?

Form of base subjunctive
The form of the base subjunctive is extremely simple. For all verbs and all persons, the form is the base of the verb, for example: be, have, do, go, sing, work
The base subjunctive does not use any other forms (goes, sings, works).

suggest-verb (or noun) + that
advise, ask, command, demand, desire, insist, order, prefer, propose, recommend, request, suggest


Source: English Club

But is is possible to use " it is recommended to do' instead of subjunctive?

@Adam Ngram suggests "yes" BUT a that clause is more popular and I would recommend using that construction in FORMAL exams

@Adam Also consider that your sentence was marked wrong because it should have been in the negative form. You don't say what the exam question was. Did you write this in an essay?

it was my essay. Okay, thank you. So, it may be because subjunctive is more formal and my writing was supposed to be formal. One more question. If I use this more colloquial version it doesn't matter if I say "it is recommended to eat before swimming" or if I use a different infinitve and say " it is recommended to have eaten before swimming". Correct?

If you want to sound informal then write: It's not a good idea to eat before swimming or words to that effect. OR "It's absolutely safe to go swimming after eating something!" You shouldn't use "it is recommended to + V" if you're writing or texting to a friend.

Yes, you are right. Could you answer my question from a previous post?

@Adam You are free to ignore or upvote my answer if you wish. But I would recommend that you read FumbleFingers answer carefully. When he says, *I think … that we all sense "We recommend to you to buy a new car" is far too "verbose". Increasingly, we tend to just go for the concise form "We recommend [that] you buy a new car".

Could you answer this? If I use this more colloquial version it doesn't matter if I say "it is recommended to eat before swimming" or if I use a different infinitve and say " it is recommended to have eaten before swimming". Correct?

Read my comments above, I say what would be an acceptable informal version. Good luck finding a grammar book or English grammar website where it says "It is recommended to buy [a second-hand car]" is correct. And why are you still going on about  eat(ing) before swimming? We normally recommend the opposite, i.e not to eat. We can also say: "People recommend not eating before swimming"

'It is important not to have eaten anything before swimming" please answer if it is correct and then I know everything.

This is your fifth question in the comments. Look at the answer(s) posted in your earlier  question.

Please, it is just one word yes or no?

"You shouldn't eat anything before...”  and that's my last comment.  Do some research, you'll learn more than being spoon-fed answers. If you do this with everyone, it's no surprise users refrain from posting answers. Think about it. Heck, ask GPT.

The sentence you wrote, "It is recommended for us to have eaten something before swimming" is grammatically correct.
The structure you used correctly expresses a suggestion or advice using a passive form (it is recommended) followed by a perfect infinitive (to have eaten). This form is appropriate for expressing actions that are advised to be completed before another action. In your case, eating before swimming.
It's possible that the sentence was marked incorrect due to a misunderstanding or a different expectation for the answer. However, from a grammatical standpoint, your sentence is well-formed.

I can get behind "It is recommended to eat something before swimming" but not I recommended for you/him/her/us/them to eat something ... That I swapped the subject "it" with another pronoun in the active voice should make no difference.

What was this misunderstanding or different expectation?

Indeed, "It is recommended to eat something before swimming" and "It is recommended for us to have eaten something before swimming" both are grammatically correct but serve slightly different stylistic purposes. The latter provides a more specific suggestion that emphasizes the action should be completed beforehand.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I don't normally downvote an answer from a new contributor but your comment is an example of sidestepping the main issue: The latter provides a more specific suggestion that emphasizes the action should be completed beforehand. It would be extremely cumbersome, not to say totally impractical, to eat something while swimming. The adverb before tells us the action of eating occurs before the act of swimming. Please site any references that recommend the construction: “I recommend FOR you/ us/ him/ her/ them to have + PP before … ”
